# How to tell what code is calling a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a method that's getting called in my iPhone app at an unexpected time, and I can't figure out what code is calling it. Is there any way to find this out from an Objective C method or an Xcode feature? Basically...

```
- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"who just called me?");
}
```

This method is called from lots of places in my code, so just searching for the method name doesn't narrow it down enough. I could temporarily add an argument to the method and then edit every call to the method to add a unique identifier as the argument, but that would require a lot of edits and then undoing all the edits when I'm done.

Ideally I would find the class and line number of the code that called this method. I don't need to use this info in the method, I just need it for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running the app through Xcode then simply set a breakpoint in your `myMethod` and run the app. When the breakpoint is reached, the app will pause and the debugger will show you the stack trace leading to the method call. Then you can see exactly what it going on.

No need to log a stack trace. Look at in real time with the debugger.

Comment: I guess I was making this more complicated than it needed to be. That works perfectly. To clarify -- when the app pauses, I can type bt into the console, or click the "spool of thread" icon between the code window and the console window to see a list of threads and the stack trace for each thread.

Comment: Yes. The debugger will show you the current stack trace in the left pane of Xcode. Or you can type in commands into the debugger window.

Answer (score 6):

You can log the call stack to see from where the method got invoked

```
- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"who just called me? %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
}
```

Comment: Confirmed -- that worked when I tried it. But rmdaddy's answer was even easier. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`NSThread +callStackSymbols`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/callStackSymbols) — you can just log that directly.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode give us a great feature "Break Point" you just need to put the break point in our method and you can see where the control reach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I've come up with. Add some code to the method that crashes the app:

```
- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"who just called me?");
    [self nonexistentMethod];
}
```

Then after the app crashes, type `bt` into the Xcode console to get a backtrace. From there I can see the last few methods that were called before this one. It's ugly but it works. Is there a better way?

Comment: log the call stack in MyMethod.